# Counting page views using webmatrix/razor

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I want a way to find out how many times a particular property page on my website is viewed.

The only way I can think of doing it, is to write an entry into the database each time the page is viewed.

If this is not the best method to do this, then I'd like to know the best practice.

I'm trying to do the following code, but it's not happening.

```
var sPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var views = "INSERT INTO PropertyViews (PropertyID, ViewTimestamp) VALUES (@0, GetDate())";
db.Execute = (views, sPropertyId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK, I've worked it out, partly with help from the link that Mike Brind posted. I was actually using an unnecessary `=` character in there. The code that works is:

```
var sPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var views = "INSERT INTO PropertyViews (PropertyID, ViewTimestamp) VALUES (@0, GetDate())";
db.Execute(views, sPropertyId);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the only way you can do this really. However, you need to invest some time in learning how to work with databases in ASP.NET Web Pages. Your syntax is not correct. I suggest reading this tutorial carefully: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: sorry, the code i posted below was something i was testing, not the actual code i was trying to get to work. Apologies. However, here is the code that i have been trying to work (replaced above), which marrys up with what's said that tutorial